Can I carry hair oil, hair lotion and shampoo in checked-in luggage if I'm travelling internationally from India to the USA?
I have a certain scalp condition, which requires me to apply a certain kind of hair oil, shampoo and hair lotion, available only here in India. I'll be traveling to the USA for graduate studies and that requires me to carry a sufficient amount of supplies beforehand as I won't be able to keep flying back and forth. I have a few questions regarding this:

I checked the TSA website but I couldn't get the bracket classification for hair oil and hair lotion (the lotion is aqueous based). Are they all considered as aerosols?
I haven't booked my air tickets yet. Will the airline have different guidelines for baggage or will the TSA supersede their requirements?
I would need to carry 2 bottles each of oil, lotion and shampoo. Each bottle is 500 ml (16.9 fl ounce [US]), so the net quantity would be 1 liter for each hair supply. Would this be an issue?
Who should I contact if I have more questions, the airline I end up booking with or the TSA?


Are you sure the stuff isn't available in the US? These days pretty much anything is available anywhere (unless there are legal or cultural/religious blockers)

@Hilmar yes, I'm sure of it, its a niche company that makes these products and i checked amazon US too, couldnt find them. The manufacturer himself said he posts it to the US but the postal charges are really exorbitant.

Aerosol is something in a pressurized container, something that comes out as spray if one pushes a button. Such products can't be transported by airplanes, or only under specific conditions. If your hair care products are not aerosols and don't contain any prohibited substances (which is not likely), you can put them into checked luggage and need not to worry. Don't attempt to transport them in a carry-on bag. More information: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule

Thanks for your answer, the reason I said aerosols was because I came across a page that marked all hair care products such as oils as aerosols which was very confusing for my. Thanks for the link too!

Also make sure to double-bag your bottles and remove as much air from the bags while sealing as possible, as pressure changes during flight can cause leaks and spills from bottles if they're not factory-sealed.  And even if they are factory sealed, it's just good practice in case of leaks during flight.  Leaks could cause a huge mess in your luggage.  Sealing them in zip bags will prevent and leaks/spills from getting where you don't want it.  Speaking from experience on this one.
